# Users are overriding eachother's sessions on my asp.net app

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Forgive me if this is a dumb question I am a newbie at asp coming from a strict desktop background. I am having an issue with users some how overriding a previous user's session on my web forms asp.net app. I created a small mobile phone web app to allow the 3 guys here at work to be able to punch in and out on their smart phones but if user A punches in and user B punches in right after then user A will see user B's punches if they refresh their phone. Furthermore if user A decides to punch out he will actually end up punching out user B. I have heard the term user state being tossed around but I thought asp.net handled that automatically? It seems to me that the server is only running one session at a time. How can I keep unique sessions running for my users?

Comment: Sounds like you probably have static fields somewhere...

Comment: I do. I keep the currently logged on user in a static property for easy access.

Comment: Are you aware that there's *one* static field for a whole AppDomain? If you have multiple users, they'll all be trampling over that same field. There's no such concept as "the currently logged on user" for a web site - there can always be multiple users.

Comment: Yes but I guess my confusion is coming from the way asp works. I was under the impression that the server ran different "sessions" or "appdomains" or "instances" if you will, for each user who visited it. Now it seems its just one long running process that everyone accesses. I'm not sure where to start on how to handle this multiple user scenario.

Comment: This may be of some help: [ASP.NET State Management Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75x4ha6s%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).  Missing from that list is [The HttpContext Items Collection](http://odetocode.com/articles/111.aspx).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I was under the impression that the server ran different "sessions" or "appdomains" or "instances" if you will, for each user who visited it.

No, that's not the case. ASP.NET does support sessions, but not in that way. You should look at [`HttpContext.Session`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.session.aspx) instead, which helps you to keep track of session-based state.

See also ["ASP.NET Session State Overview"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx) for more information.

Comment: Thanks a ton! Just got my app working correctly. It was a lot easier than I thought it was going to be.